# Can the trajectory $x(t) = (\sin t, \sin 2t)$, $t \in \mathbb{R}$, ever be the solution to a first order autonomous system?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to know whether the trajectory $x(t) = (\sin t, \sin 2t)$, $t \in \mathbb{R}$, can ever be the solution to a first order autonomous system.

I have no idea how to go about trying to construct a system that it would solve, but also not sure how to disprove it. We were given the exercise just after proving the group property of flows $\phi_{s+t}(x)=\phi_t(\phi_s(x))$ so I wasn't sure whether to try and show that this trajectory does not satisfy this, but when trying to simplify $\phi_t(\phi_s(x))=\phi_t(\sin s, \sin 2s)$ I got stuck.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you be a little more precise about what you mean by a first order autonomous system? $\dot y = 1$, $x = ( \sin y ,\sin 2 y)$.

Comment: @copper.hat I mean $\dot{x}=f(x)$ for some function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$. Apologies if this was unclear!

Comment: It is worth plotting the flow to see why this is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $\dot{x} = f(x)$. Note that $x(0) = x(\pi)$ (and hence $f(x(0)) = f(x(\pi))$), but $\dot{x}(0) \neq \dot{x}(\pi)$.

Answer (score 0):

It will require the characteristic equation have roots $i, 2i$

$(\lambda^2 + 1)(\lambda^2 + 4) = 0\\
\lambda^4 + 5\lambda^2 + 4 = 0\\
y'''' + 5y'' +  4y = 0$

That is not first order, but it is autonomous.

We could also do it like this.

$\mathbf x' = \begin {bmatrix} 0&1&0&0\\-1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&4\\0&0&-4&0 \end{bmatrix} \mathbf x$

Comment: What does a characteristic equation mean for a system $\dot{x} = f(x)$? It is not necessarily linear.